# Webcast based website in php

Tags: php, html, video-streaming, video-capture

I have a client who's requirement is that he wants a website which would be able to stream through uploaded videos through search. And the most demanding requirement is that they have certain events held every week and they want those events covered and recorded on camera and this video should be visible on the website live.

I know how to make website in php but I don't know what is the requirement for a webcast based website specially the camera and bandwidth requirement.

```
Also what are the requirements and methods for a website which can stream videos uploaded on server.I am totally new to video streaming and don't know how to do it in php.
```

Please explain me the way to implement it.

Comment: if you put them on youtube, you don't have to worry about bandwidth

Comment: And even though you don't know how to do that - you still was hired?

Comment: I have to give the client the requirements for the site and camera, my role will be to develop site modules which i can and the client has other guys for other tasks according to the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the HTML5 webcam capture.

It was highlighted during Google IO.

I think you need to Google for the method. I have not really used it just yet.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Red5 that could be more suitable for what you are trying to do is the Nginx-RTMP module. https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module If you currently use, or can use Nginx, the module is easy to configure and work with. It can accept and feed live video over RTMP to flash-based players like JWplayer, and simultaneously create HTTP Live Streams for playing on Apple devices (and other devices like ROKU, etc.).

I have it setup on a couple servers, and have been very pleased with the results. It accepts video over RTMP and just does a great job IMHO.

With Nginx-RTMP, I use scripts that run ffmpeg to stream pre-recorded files "live" to the server. And then when we actually want to have a real live video feed, just stop ffmpeg and stream from our live location either with a computer running ffmpeg (like from a studio with a video feed), or with OSBroadcaster on a phone or tablet, or really any software or app that can stream video over RTMP.

You can automate all this with some PHP back-end, so your pre-recorded material automatically gets stored on the server (Nginx-RTMP can record your stream too) and displayed on the proper page in an HTML5 video element or flash-based video player, or both. And when the live feed is actually live, you can have PHP show a player window on your page that is displaying the live stream.

This is over-simplified of course, but hopefully you can get a feel for how it works.

See also [How to set up your own private RTMP server using nginx](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/how-to-set-up-your-own-private-rtmp-server-using-nginx.50/) for more info on the Nginx-RTMP module.

As for camera, it totally depends on the situation, and that's kindof a whole other arena. You could use something like a webcam, or a tablet/smartphone that streams via RTMP, or a professional camera that feeds into a computer running an RTMP client streamer like ffmpeg (I think VLC works too). Or Teradek and some other companies make some little hardware boxes (Teradek Vidiu) that you can plug in a video input and they will encode and stream the video over RTMP to whatever server you specify.

Bandwidth depends on a lot of factors: how many viewers you will have, the video quality and resolution, and how many simultaneous streams you need to support (multiple live streams from different locations, etc.)

Your upload bandwidth (camera to your streaming server) can range from 100kbps or so on up to a few Mbps, depending on the requirements for your video. To give you a typical example though, if you are streaming standard definition video at 24-30 frames per second, with a good codec like h.264, you can expect a decent quality stream to take up around 400-700kbps. It can vary a lot from that, but that's a good starting point. If you are sending 720p30, you may want to use about 1-1.5Mbps or so. 1080p30, maybe 1.5-3Mbps, UHD, 5-6Mbps. But like I said your choice of bitrate will vary based on your quality needs.

Then what you stream out, you multiply that rate by the number of viewers that you want to support, add one more for your upload stream, and you have your total bandwidth needed. There are other things to take into consideration, but you have your starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of research and found that we have to use a flash kind of server.
For that we have 2 choices : RED5 and Flash.
RED5 being open source while Flash is not free.
for such kind of webcasting we require such server installed and then use the appropriate api and embed the flash player into your webpages.
These special servers are required as we need to process requests without refreshing the page and then load the content dynamically.